# Window opened from a class is not displaying correctly

Tags: python, pyqt5

If I open a window from the main() method it is displayed correctly.

[image]

If I open the same window out of a class instantiated from the main() method (WorkerClass), the window is only partially displayed, all the content inside (e.g. a QText) edit is missing.

[image]

Here's the code I used to reproduce this with a minimal amount of code:

```
import sys, time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
        
class StatusWindow(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def appendText(self, text):
        self.append(text)
 
class WorkerClass(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def openWindow(self):
        s = StatusWindow()
        s.show()
        s.appendText('opened from WorkerClass')
        
        time.sleep(10)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = StatusWindow()
    win.show()
    win.appendText('opened from main()')
    
    work = WorkerClass()
    work.openWindow()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What goe's wrong here? How to fix this example to be able to get the window opened from WorkerClass displayed correctly?

Comment: First of all, no blocking functions (including while loops) should ever happen in UI related code, so remove the `time.sleep`. Then, if you're planning on using that WorkerClass in a separate thread, and you're going to create that window from that thread, then don't: creation and access to UI elements is not allowed from external threads, and you must use Qt signals and slots instead.

Comment: `time.sleep` is there to keep the window open for a limited amout of time. Without `time.sleep` the window closes immediately, which might be  related to my problem. 
Worker is missleading here as there is no plan to place this in a thread.

Comment: `time.sleep` is **exactly** the reason for which you can't see the contents of the window: it blocks the event queue, so the UI becomes unresponsive and is not correctly painted (with `sleep` you're blocking *all* events, including important ones such as `paintEvent`, which is responsible of drawing the widgets). Make the window an instance member (change `s = StatusWindow()` to `self.s = StatusWindow()`) and use a singleShot if you want to close it after a certain amount of time (`QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, self.s.close)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to musicamante, know I understand what happens.

The StatusWindow would also build correctly if instantiated from WorkerClass. If `time.sleep` is replaced by the `Qtimer` you can proove this.

In my example the window is not build correctly as the whole application is too busy, here simulated with `time.sleep`, and will never find the time to properly finish the window as long WorkerClass is running.